# WMAppManifest and store applications

Tags: windows-phone-8, version, manifest, windows-phone-store

I was wondering what the proper way to get and handle WMAppManifest version is for Windows Phone 8 applications.

Basically, my case is this: I want to implement a check that will not let the user use the app if it is not the latest version. In this case I want to check the version number of the user. Currently I do it like this:

```
        var docRoot = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Root;
        string versionString = docRoot.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
        string clientString = docRoot.Element("App").Attribute("Title").Value;
```

However, when I upload the manifest to store a version number is asked upon upgrading the XAP. So my question is, how do I get the version stored in the base and/or will the store update the WMAppManifest automatically so when I upload my package, can I assume for my app manifest (Retrieved by XDocument.Load) to contain the version I entered when uploading it to the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of your project is stored in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

This one: `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

You can get assembly information via reflection: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` (search for the `FullName` property).

So you don't have to query the WMAppManifest (and really shouldn't). The version number in the WMAppManifest and AssemblyInfo always have to be kept in sync!

The version number which you have to enter in the dashboard is used for the store and not automatically fetched from the manifest.

To sum up, there are 3 places where you have to maintain the version number. But you should always query it from the AssemblyInfo!

Comment: Alright, thanks. That cleared things up. I did feel kinda iffy using WMAppManifest directly to begin with. :P

Comment: Hmh, is there official source for this information? :) So I can basically 1) leave AssemblyInfo.cs and WMAppManifest.xml to 1.0.0.0. 2) Upload XAP to Windows Store and type in version 3) Use System.Reflection.Assembly to query version number, and it should return what ever I entered in Windows Store version prompt? I wonder what would querying WMAppManifest return in this case?

Comment: That's just the way I have experienced this situation, no source. And no, it does not return the Store version, but the version number you have entered in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guidance on Windows Phone app versioning in MSDN, neither by updating AssemblyInfo.cs 
or WMAppmanifest.xml file.

For WMAppmanifest.xml MSDN only states having capabilities etc. up to date http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx

I think AssemblyInfo.cs is a bit of a historial remain from versioning DLL libraries, and maintaining reference to right version of lib.

For me WMAppmanifest.xml feels more "natural place" (on Android/IOS version is also  specified in manifest/separate text file) placing version number among other information (capabilities etc). I also use manifest file (package.appxmanifest) in Windows 8/8.1 Store Apps.

In Windows 8 Apps you can access manifest file via Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current class, which for me, indicates that Microsoft has given more thought on placement of version number in manifest file.

**Windows Phone Store doesn't process any of these files, so it really shouldn't matter where you keep it.**